# ValueError: not enough values to unpack when using scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to classify the iris dataset using naive bayes and decision trees from scikit-learn. I got a ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2). What's wrong with my code? I checked the docs for `train_test_split`. The inputs and outputs seem to match.

```
from sklearn import naive_bayes, tree, metrics
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from random import seed
from math import sqrt
from math import pi
from math import exp

# get all data
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# get raw data and lable
iris_data = iris.data
iris_labels = list(iris.target)

labeled_data = list(zip(iris_data, iris_labels))

# run the designated classifier
def run_classifier(classifier, training, testing):
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)

    expect = testing[1]
    predict = classifier.predict(testing[0])
    
    return expect, predict

# collect data on training size plateau
def simulate():
    # progress through range of testing data sizes
    nb_acc = []
    tree_acc = []
    training_fracs = [x/1000 for x in range(500, 850, 25)]

    for i in training_fracs:
        nb = sklearn.naive_bayes.CategoricalNB()
        dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=25)
      
        nb_expect, nb_predict = run_classifier(nb, training_set, testing_set)
        dt_expect, dt_predict = run_classifier(dt, training_set, testing_set)
        
        nb_acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(nb_expect, nb_predict))
        tree_acc.append(metrics.accuracy_score(dt_expect, dt_predict))
        
    return nb_acc, tree_acc, training_fracs
        
nb_acc, tree_acc, training_fracs = simulate()

print(f"Naive Bayes accuracy @ 50% training: {nb_acc[0]}")
print(f"Decision Tree accuracy @ 50% training: {tree_acc[0]}")


> 
    > ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
    > > last) <ipython-input-536-cedfcfcdf7fa> in <module>
    > >      28     return nb_acc, tree_acc, training_fracs
    > >      29 
    > > ---> 30 nb_acc, tree_acc, training_fracs = simulate()
    > >      31 
    > >      32 print(f"Naive Bayes accuracy @ 50% training: {nb_acc[0]}")
    > > 
    > > <ipython-input-536-cedfcfcdf7fa> in simulate()
    > >      18         nb = sklearn.naive_bayes.CategoricalNB()
    > >      19         dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    > > ---> 20         X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=25)
    > >      21 
    > >      22         nb_expect, nb_predict = run_classifier(nb, training_set, testing_set)
    > > 
    > > ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

Comment: Printing the problematic code is the *first* line of defense... why don't you try printing the output of `train_test_split()` *instead* of unpacking? Obviously the output isn't conducive to unpacking 4 values so your data going in might be incorrectly formatted.

Comment: Looking at your code more closely, there are numerous issues. I'm guessing you're working in a Jupyter notebook since you didn't report any `NameError` exceptions which this code would raise, running it by itself. I'm assuming some of these things were previously defined during your session. I'm willing to bet that the issue is that you're passing a `df` to `train_test_split()` but `df` is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split) gives this example:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Note how `x` and `y` are passed in while you only pass in a single `df` value, so you probably only get 2 values returned instead of the 4 you expect.